# Create JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I have json data as the following list.

**"keyword":['agr','case','coffee','tea']**

I need to convert this data into the following format in Python.

```
  {
            "typeName": "keyword",
            "multiple": true,
            "typeClass": "compound",
            "value": [
              {
                "keywordValue": {
                  "typeName": "keywordValue",
                  "multiple": false,
                  "typeClass": "primitive",
                  "value": "agr"
                },
                "keywordValue": {
                  "typeName": "keywordValue",
                  "multiple": false,
                  "typeClass": "primitive",
                  "value": "case"
                }...

                },
                "keywordVocabulary": {
                  "typeName": "keywordVocabulary",
                  "multiple": false,
                  "typeClass": "primitive",
                  "value": "vocab"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```

Here is a part from my code. But it takes only the last item of key[] and creates 1 **keywordValue** object.

```
for key in keyword:
                    keyword = {
                        'typeName': 'keyword',
                        'multiple': True,
                        'typeClass': 'compound',
                        'value': [
                            {
                                'keywordValue': {
                                    'typeName': 'keywordValue',
                                    'multiple': False,
                                    'typeClass': 'primitive',
                                    'value': key
                                },
                                'keywordVocabulary': {
                                    'typeName': 'keywordVocabulary',
                                    'multiple': False,
                                    'typeClass': 'primitive',
                                    'value': 'test'
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

Comment: What is `keyword`? Please provide [mcve] with `import` lines.

Comment: In the first example, `'keywordValue'` exists multiple times in the same dictionary, which isn't valid.  Do you have a square bracket in the wrong place?  It would make more sense before `'keywordVocabulary'`.

Comment: Values are different for each keywordValue, it is a standard format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to take the values from a json file and load them into Python, the json library helps with this. It reads in the values and saves it as a dictionary.

```
from json import loads
dictionary = loads(open(input_file, "r").read())
```

To access the values of "typeName", use `typeNameValue = dictionary["typeName"]`

If the values of a keyword are multiple dictionaries within it, like `value`, it will keep creating dictionaries in the values. If you need to access the `multiple` key in `keywordVocabulary`, use `multiple = dictionary["value"]["keywordVocabulary"]["multiple"]`